# Linked List: trying to change index of node

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void changeIndex(FrameNode **head, int numOfFrames)
{
    int frameIndex = 0, i = 0;
    char name[STR_LEN];
    FrameNode* curr = *head;
    FrameNode* prev = NULL;
    FrameNode* nodeToChange = NULL;
    printf("Enter the name of the frame:\n");
    fgets(name, STR_LEN, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    while (!(searchFrame(head, numOfFrames, name)))
    {
        printf("Name is not exist in the list\n Please enter another name:");
        fgets(name, STR_LEN, stdin);
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    }
    printf("Enter the index of the frame:\n");
    scanf("%d", &frameIndex);
    while (frameIndex > numOfFrames || frameIndex < 0)
    {   
        printf("Name is not exist in the list\n Please enter another name:");
        scanf("%d", &frameIndex);
    }
    getchar();
    while (curr != NULL && i < numOfFrames)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, curr->frame->name) == 0)
        {
            nodeToChange = createFrame(head, numOfFrames, curr->frame->path, curr->frame->duration, curr->frame->name);
            numOfFrames++;
            numOfFrames = deleteFrame(head, numOfFrames, curr->frame->name);
        }
        curr = curr->next;
        i++;
    }
    curr = *head;
    i = 0;
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        while (i != frameIndex && curr->next != NULL)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            i++;
        }
        prev->next = nodeToChange;
        nodeToChange->next = curr;
    }
    else
    {
        *head = nodeToChange;
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to change the index of a node by its name. I've got a node that has a struct inside.
It throws me an error which says that `prev = NULL` even thought I init it in the 4th while (the right value is set in `nodeToChange`).

So my question is why it is happening and how you can suggest me to fix it?

Comment: After entering new name for frame why you again use strcmp(name,curr->frame->name) and already you have done that while accepting string from gets by `searchframe`

Comment: Existing linked list node placement isn't about creating new nodes; it's about modifying pointers. Finding some node and moving it to the n'th position should involve getting the pointers to the prospect node, detaching the node, and inserting it into the new position, all by pointer-only modifications. If you're creating a new node and deleting the old one, you should rethink this.

Comment: What is`index of a node`? BTW: put your list-management into a separate function, just like you did with `searchFrame()`

Comment: @Onk_r Because i have aleread checked the name the he contains

Answer (score 0):

For value of  `i= 0` and `frameindex=0` then condition of while loop fails so then `prev` is already `null` and you are going to access `prev->next` that raises error.

Add one condition for `i=0&&frameindex==0`
And update entry condition of while loop to `i<frameindex` instead of `i!=frameindex`

Comment: @Onl_r I didn't get the first part I dont change frameIndex